# Can a function be a parameter of a function definition

Tags: python, function

When we are defining our custom functions can we add another function as one of our parameters. I was wandering on this problem and quite didn't get the concept behind this.

Here are some examples that confused me.

```
def func1(x,y=len()):
    pass
```

I want to know what happens in these function parameters when we call them

And I appreciate If some can point out what are all the ways to implement a function with another function as a parameter.

Comment: @tdelaney I don't know isn't this good enough to be posted

Comment: Both of your examples raise SyntaxError. You'll need to post working code to get a good answer.

Comment: This is good enough to be posted but your examples are not valid python. You'll need to figure out better examples.

Comment: @tdelaney can you look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are objects like anything else. Once you've defined one

```
>>> def foo(param):
...     return "Do all the " + param
...
```

You can pass it to another function and have that function do the call

```
>>> def bar_1(func, param):
...     print(func(param))
... 
>>> bar_1(foo, "things")
Do all the things
```

You can use the function object as a default parameter

```
>>> def bar_2(func=foo, param=""):
...     print(func(param))
... 
>>> bar_2()
Do all the
```

You can even call a function and use its result to set the default for a parameter

```
>>> def bar_3(text=foo("things")):
...     print(text)
... 
>>> bar_3()
Do all the things
```

But you can't call a function to define the parameter name itself. Here, it appears that you want the result of `len()` (which returns an int - or in this case fails) to be the name of a parameter, but that violates python's syntax rules.

```
>>> def func1(x,y,len()):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def func1(x,y,len()):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code examples both have syntax errors, so it's unclear what you're after exactly.

But yes, you can pass in a function as a parameter to another function. Common examples are callback functions or functions that you may want to apply in the course of another.

Here's an example:

```
# print_os takes an integer and prints that many o's
def print_os(n):
    print('o' * n)


# here, f is expected to be a function, any function that takes an integer
def for_multiples_of_three(xs, f):
    for x in xs:
        if x % 3 == 0:
            f(x)


for_multiples_of_three([2, 6, 1, 9, 4, 5, 3], print_os)
```

Result:

```
oooooo
ooooooooo
ooo
```

Or this:

```
def first_letter(s):
    return s[0] if s else ''


def for_each_word(s, f):
    return [f(x) for x in s.split()]


print(for_each_word('Not a very useful function', first_letter))
```

Result:

```
['N', 'a', 'v', 'u', 'f']
```

The important thing to note is that a function is just another thing you can do something with in Python. Similar to assigning a number, string or other object to a variable to be able to use it later, you can assign a function to a variable and call it later.

The error in your examples is that you added the `()`, which means Python tries to call the function and obtain a result from them - and then passes the result into the next function. That's not calling a function with a function, that's calling a function with the result of another function:

```
def three():
    return 3

def print_sum(x, y):
    print(x+y)

print_sum(2, three())
```

Result:

```
5
```

Comment: thank you very much it helped me understanding functions

Comment: No problem, if you think it answered your question, please click the check mark, so others can find it as well and people writing answers know it's been answered